# VNC on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: server, vnc, .desktop

I have found a couple of tutorials on this...but they all suggest installing a separate desktop shell to really use this. But, I do have Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop installed, since this is a local server, and which is actually connected to my monitor. But, it is really inconvenient to keep swapping my keyboard and mouse cords to the little Ubuntu box... Instead, I'd just like to use the GUI from my main computer.

How do I set up a VNC server, that will bring me to the very screen of my Ubuntu login? I have already enabled automated login, now I just would like to access it's screen so I can use a few GUI-only applications.

Answer (score 1):

Default VNC server that comes with Ubuntu 18.04 Vino.

For setting up go to System Settings>Sharing

Default VNC client that comes with Ubuntu 18.04 is Remmina.

To turn of encryption run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
```

[image: Vino]

Comment: What if I have no access to the actual screen? This answer did help - but I found an issue I had to deal with by using `gsettings` to turn off encryption. Anyway, how do I turn this on off the command line?

Comment: `gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false`